# Trigger nested Jenkins job from VSTS build

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've configured a service hook in VSTS to connect to Jenkins. I'm able to use the Jenkins extension to trigger a Jenkins job if it's not in a subfolder. E.g. http://myhost/job/Always%20succeed/

In that case, I can simply connect like this and run my job:
[image]

If my job is nested, however, I can't figure out how to connect. Here's an example: http://myhost/view/Production/job/Automation/job/Test/job/My%20Job

I've tried using just the name (e.g. "My Job"), the whole url, and a dot notation (Production.Automation.Test.My Job). How can I make this run and where can I find more documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty nuanced and one could argue buggy. First off, I can reach the same job with two urls:

`http://myhost/view/Production/job/Automation/job/Test/job/My%20Job`
`http://myhost/job/Automation/job/Test/job/My%20Job`

Turns out the latter is the way to go.

I tried the following name, and it tried reaching the corresponding endpoint:

`Automation/job/Test/job/My%20Job <- name used in VSTS "Job name" field
/job/Automation/job/job/Test/job/My%20Job/build <- url attempted, failed (404)`

Note the double `job/`. Then I tried the following with better results:

`Automation/Test/job/My%20Job <- name used`
`/job/Automation/job/Test/job/My%20Job/build <- url tried, success`

It's a bit concerning that the pattern isn't consistent regarding the double "job/" part but whatever.